# Criptografia e seus bits. Como explicar?

Tags: criptografia

Tenho esta tabela de criptografia tirada de um livro, porém eu não entendi como ela funciona.

- Por que o Número de chaves alternativas é 2 elevado a 32? Por que cada bit cabe 0 e 1?
- Por que o número necessário para descriptografar é o número de bits menos 1?
- O que seria o 26 caracteres (permutação)
- Algo a acrescentar?

Preciso de ajuda rápido, por favor respondam minha pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Criptografia e o tempo necessário para descriptografá-las. fonte: (STALLINGS, 2008,  p.21)**

Fonte: STALLINGS, William. **Criptografia e segurança de redes** - princípios e praticas.

Comment: `26! - 4 x 10^26` deveria ser `26! = 4 x 10^26`, não?

Comment: Tenho algo a acrescentar sim: essas colunas "tempo necessário para descriptografia" não fazem o menor sentido fora de contexto - um computador mais rápido (ou um cluster) levaria menos tempo que a média, um algoritmo paralelizável (diagamos, AES-CTR) levaria menos tempo que um não paralelizável (tipo AES-CBC), uma criptografia assimétrica (digamos RSA ou Diffie-Hellman em Zp) levaria menos tempo que uma simétrica para o mesmo tamanho de chave, etc. Sei que isso não faz parte da pergunta, mas achei bom frisar. No contexto do livro deve haver uma justificativa para esses números, contudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Por que cada bit cabe 0 e 1?

No sistema binário, um bit (**bi**nary digi**t**) pode assumir apenas dois valores.

Eles estão sendo representados por 0 e 1, mas isso é apenas uma convenção. Em alguns contextos podem ser interpretados como valores lógicos (verdadeiro/falso, sim/não), sinais algébricos (+/-), estados de ativação (on/off), ou qualquer outro atributo com dois valores, desde que sejam **dois** valores, por causa da natureza do sistema **bi**nário.

### Por que o número de chaves alternativas é 2 elevado a 32?

Primeiramente, entenda "alternativo" como "possibilidade" (que é uma das definições pra essa palavra no dicionário, e me parece bem mais didático).

O cálculo de possibilidades é abordado na matemática no estudo de combinatória. Como o valor dos bits pode repetir na chave, trata-se de um [arranjo com repetição](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Arranjo_com_repeti.C3.A7.C3.A3o), que é dado por:

> **n<sup>r</sup>**, sendo que **n** é o total de elementos e **r** é o número de elementos escolhidos.

Como um bit pode assumir dois valores, há duas possibilidades naquela posição da chave, portanto, dois elementos a serem contados (n=2) no estudo de combinação. Numa chave de 32 bits, há 32 elementos escolhidos: r=32.

Portanto:

- Possiblidades numa chave de 1 bit: 2<sup>1</sup> = 2 `(0, 1)`
- Possiblidades numa chave de 2 bits: 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 `(00, 01, 10, 11)`
- Possiblidades numa chave de 32 bits: 2<sup>32</sup>

### Por que o número de tentativas necessárias é 2<sup>r-1</sup>?

Porque 2<sup>r-1</sup> é a metade do número de possibilidades 2<sup>r</sup>. Como podemos acabar descobrindo a chave na primeira, na última ou em qualquer tentativa, usamos como aproximação o número médio de tentativas, que, arredondando, equivale à metade das possibilidades.  A [resposta do ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68390/6267) explica isso com bem mais detalhes.

### O que seria o 26 caracteres (permutação)?

Ao invés de medir a chave em bits, como ele fez nas outras linhas, dessa vez ele mede em caracteres. Para calcular as possibilidades de chaves com 26 caracteres (sendo que cada caractere pode ser qualquer um das 26 letras do alfabeto) usa-se `n!`, nesse caso, `26!`. Isso é uma [permutação simples](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Permuta.C3.A7.C3.B5es_simples).

Answer (score 6):

Respondendo à pergunta de porque o número de tentativas necessárias pra descriptografar é metade do número de possibilidades, suponha que você monta um baralho gigante, onde de um lado de cada carta está escrita uma possível chave de descriptografia, e do outro está escrito “sim” ou “não”, dependendo se a chave é a chave certa ou não.

Se você tem N cartas e você sabe que o adversário escolheu a chave de forma suficientemente aleatória, a carta vencedora vai estar com probabilidade igual em cada uma das N posições (i.e. 1/N). Se você numerar as cartas do topo pro fundo do baralho de 1 a N, o número de tentativas que você precisa fazer pra achar a chave certa é o número daquela carta: se a chave for a 17ª carta do baralho, você vai fazer 17 tentativas até achar a chave certa.

Só que a gente não *sabe* qual é a carta certa; a gente quer saber qual é o número *médio* de tentativas que a gente precisa fazer pra achar a carta certa. Com probabilidade 1/N esse número é 1 (quando a chave certa é a primeira carta do baralho); com probabilidade 1/N esse número é 2 (quando a chave certa é a segunda carta do baralho); …; com probabilidade 1/N esse número é N (quando a chave certa é a última carta do baralho).

Logo o número médio de tentativas que você precisa fazer é

```
  1/N * 1 + 1/N * 2 + 1/N * 3 + … + 1/N * (N-1) + 1/N * N =
= 1/N (1 + 2 + 3 + … + (N-1) + N) =
= 1/N * N * (N+1) / 2 =
= (N+1) / 2
```

Pra esses algoritmos que a gente está falando, N é descomunal; esse +1 é um em conta de bilhão. Logo é uma aproximação muito boa afirmar que o número médio de tentativas é N/2.

---

Toda a discussão acima supõe que a senha é, de fato, aleatória, mas o fato é que na prática as coisas não funcionam assim — as pessoas escolhem datas de aniversário, números de telefone, … como senhas.

Pra ajudar a proteger os usuários nestes casos, é popular você usar uma *key stretching function*, como [bcrypt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), scrypt ou PBKDF2: essas funções são funções hash complicadas (como toda função hash) e *caras* (ao contrário de MD5 e SHA-*).

A ideia é que você gera uma string aleatória `s` e usa `f(s, x)` pra criptografar
o arquivo (onde `x` é a senha que o usuário vai decorar); você guarda `s` em aberto, junto com o arquivo criptografado. A ideia é que se você sabe e.g. que o usuário escolheu `x` como um número de oito dígitos, se você criptografar o arquivo do jeito ingênuo, o seu adversário só precisa fazer, em média, 5 * 10^7 descriptografias pra abrir o seu arquivo.

Quando você tem uma *key stretching function*, você coloca o seu adversário contra a parede: calcular `f(s, x)` é muito custoso; ele continua abrindo o seu arquivo após 5 * 10^7 tentativas, mas cada uma dessas tentativas é muito mais custosa (em geral esse custo é ajustável, mas pra aplicações “civis” em geral a galera ajusta pra `f(s, x)` demorar um segundo pra ser calculado num computador moderno).

A *outra* opção é você ignorar a existência de `f` e tentar achar a chave de criptografia diretamente, mas isso é inviável se você estiver usando um algoritmo com uma chave de 128 bits, por exemplo.